# Can not get the value of id with vue $refs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I see the about vue $ refs document, the console to see is {}, I do not know how to get the value of id?
There `{ }` is no object, how to get $ refs id of value,but I think this `{}` not get to object.I try to use `console.log(this.$refs.dataInfo.id)` is `undefined`.

Look at the picture：
[image]

javascript file:

```
console.log(this.$refs)
```

HTML file:

```
<tab-item v-for="item in category" :id="item.id" ref="dataInfo">{{item.name}}</tab-item>
```

Comment: for one, it's all in `{}.branid` not just `{}` as you can see in the object tree, it starts off with `{}` but the item is `branid` which contains another item, `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log(this.$refs.dataInfo.id)` is `undefined` because you are trying to access an element's attribute through a reference to a component. Based on your example object, you can access it like this: `this.$refs.dataInfo[0]['$el'].id`

That's an odd way of doing it, I believe. The Vue way of doing it would be:

1. Using [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events). When props change in the child component and you want to do something about it in the parent component, you should emit a custom event. You'd do something like this in the child component: `this.$emit('dataChange', data)`. And in the parent component add an event listener `@dataChange="myMethod"` to the component. [image: Parent-child component relationship in Vue.js]
2. Using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

Having a good understanding of the basic concepts such as how the data flows in the application is a must and should not be overlooked!